Why is a custom field not visible under Object's Fields and Relations
I have a custom field Notes__c on Task object, but I'm not able to find t under Fields and Relations of Task object. Even my repo is not having this field under Task object. How is this text field created?
I'm Sys admin and I'm able to see that this field as R/W access in the profile and I'm able to query the field in inspector too but unable to find in the fields and relations.
Inspector:

Fields and relations of Task object:

Profile permission:


Task and Event are essentially instances of the Activity object.
This has likely been created on Activity, so you should be able to find it under Fields and Relationships there.

Since Events and Tasks are both part of the Activities object, you will need to see your custom field in the Activity object.
In Salesforce Classic:

Go to Setup.
Enter Activities in the Quick Find box.
Click on
Activity Custom Fields.
Click on New.

In Lightning Experience:

Click on the gear icon on the top right.
Click on Setup.
Click on Object Manager.
Enter Activity in the Quick Find box and click the
Activity label to open the object's setup.
On the left side, click on
Fields & Relationships.
Click on New.

To differentiate between Task and Event custom fields, select the appropriate page layouts on step 4 of 4 during the field creation process. The field can be added to both Tasks and Events or just one of the objects.

Another GPT generated answer, by appearance.

@PhilW, You are wrong. This is not generated from the GPT. This answer is a reference from the Salesforce article.

Fair enough. So you know, what makes it look GPT is the overly detailed list of steps you have provided. This level of detail is unnecessary. In future, I recommend you cite your source when you base an answer on a blog post or documentation, rather than your own experience or learning.
